# Sending a mail via php script in ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, email

I am trying to send a mail to my gmail id via php script in ubuntu but unable to send it.
My code

```
<html>
<head><title>Send mail</title></head>
<body >


<?php
$name=$email=$query="";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
 $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
   $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   $query = test_input($_POST["query"]);
 if(mail("abc@gmail.com","Subject",$query,"From: $email\n")){
 echo "email send";
}else{
echo "not send";
}
}
function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Name:<input type="text" name="name" required>


  Email id:<input type="email" name="email" required>
    Query:<textarea name="query" row="5" cols="40" required></textarea>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have configured my php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = 

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path ="/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"

extension=php_openssl.dll //removed semicolon
```

output /var/log/mail.log

```
Jul 27 11:09:59 ak-VirtualBox postfix/smtp[5598]: 7069320869: to=<abc@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.129.26]:25, delay=4.9, delays=0.08/0.08/2.9/1.8, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.129.26] said: 550-5.7.1 [14.98.28.24      12] Our system has detected that this message is 550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for 550 5.7.1 more information. kr8si13914201pbc.32 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Jul 27 11:09:59 ak-VirtualBox postfix/cleanup[5596]: 4AA162086D: message-id=<20140727053959.4AA162086D@ak-VirtualBox>
Jul 27 11:09:59 ak-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[4781]: 4AA162086D: from=<>, size=2908, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 27 11:09:59 ak-VirtualBox postfix/bounce[5606]: 7069320869: sender non-delivery notification: 4AA162086D
Jul 27 11:09:59 ak-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[4781]: 7069320869: removed
Jul 27 11:09:59 ak-VirtualBox postfix/local[5608]: 4AA162086D: to=<daemon@ak-VirtualBox>, relay=local, delay=0.12, delays=0.06/0.01/0/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jul 27 11:09:59 ak-VirtualBox postfix/qmgr[4781]: 4AA162086D: removed
```

when I am submitting the form it showing email send(as per my script) but i dint receive any email in my gmail id.Is there any configuration and installation i am missing?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you see in `/var/log/maillog`?  And .. you've tagged this question with [tag:linux] and mentioned Ubunto, but your configuration mentions `php_openssl.dll`.  You've also included both the Windows-only and the Unix-only php.ini mail configuration.  What operating system are you *really* running?

Comment: Try something like this `smtp_port=465` instead of 25

Comment: @ghoti updated my question,i have ubuntu 14 in my virtualbox installed in windows 8(host)

Comment: @SpencerX still not getting anything in my inbox

Comment: So...  Looks like the first line of the log you posted contains an explanation.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about email deliverability, not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

In your first line, the log says specifically:

`Our system has detected that this message is 550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for 550 5.7.1 more information. kr8si13914201pbc.32 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))`

Gmail (and most other mailing services) uses a combination of the sending domain reputation, mail transfer/sending server's status (blacklisted etc), number of request frequency, number of recipients and mail content to determine if the mail is a spam.

If it determines it is not, it delivers it to the inbox, in case of medium severity it routes it to the spam folder. If the rating is really low, it blocks the mail - as in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Does the DNS on your server forward and reverse correctly?  If not, that would explain why mail from your server is being treated as spam.

To see if your mail server has a glaring problem that would cause other mail servers to think it's a spammer, try sending a message from your mail server to check-auth@verifier.port25.com. This service will do a bunch of checks, and you'll get a report back with ton of information, such whether or not your mail server's DNS is setup correctly, whether your mail server's IP is on any black lists, if you have a problem with your SPF records, etc.